# Installed 13.04 alongside Windows 7, now I can't boot into Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, windows-7

I thought I installed Ubuntu to the same partition as windows 7. I thought that was what I was supposed to do, but now I can't boot into Windows.

When I try to boot into Windows, it tells me "boot manager missing" and then the screen turns into a collage of colors. I even tried to re-install Windows 7, but after the "windows is loading files" progress bar, it turns into a collage of colors again and nothing happens.

The only thing I can do is restart my PC and boot up Ubuntu. I'm thinking the only way to fix this is by formatting my HDD and re-installing Windows 7, but I would prefer to not lose all my files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Comment: Why is a question from 2013 just now being closed as a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely haven't installed it into same partition as it would have deleted Windows.

Linux uses a much better partition system which Windows can't use. When manually adjusting the partitions, rather then using automatic option offered, it is important to keep Windows as the first partition because Windows Boot Manager can't find its files if they are elsewhere. You do not need to format your disk, but that would be the quickest way.

*You can skip the boring solution and jump to recommended way if you like.*

The most effective way would be to swap partitions; it is very complex but possible. The longer but easier way is to copy content from Windows home directories into Ubuntu, then using some live distro (for example SystemRescueCD or GParted CD), you can do it using GParted to
delete the Windows partition and moving all the partitions to the right.  This will take your computer the whole day to go through.

Once done, reinstall Windows (only up to the stage where it wants to restart).

Now use the live CD from which you installed your Ubuntu and install grub again.

Boot into grub and copy your old home directory back.
Reboot and chose grub's entry for Windows and finish the Windows installation.

**Now the easy and recommended way:**

- Install VirtualBox
- copy the full contents of the Windows partition into it

If it doesn't start working straight away, make a new installation choosing not to format the drive in the process.

Don't forget that instead of usual drivers you will need VirtualBox Guest Additions.

Now you can remove the Windows partition. Using some live distro, increase Linux's partition size.